# MySql, is there a way to convert Integer field into Varchar without losing data?

Tags: mysql, integer, schema, varchar

I would like to change a table's schema so that one Integer field changes to Varchar one, but keep the data (previous numbers will now be strings).

Comment: No, by 'one' i meant field. If it's important the final field should be varchar(10).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this to alter the schema:

```
alter table table_name change col_name col_name varchar(10)
```

Comment: Will this wipe the data or not? I'm asking because of 'try' in your answer.

Comment: this won't swipe your data. you are just going to change the type from integer to varchar